# Precision of double when reading from file

Tags: c++, io, double, precision, fstream

I'm trying to read `double` values from a file into a `std::vector`. However, I've noticed that the values do not match what is on the file, but has a slight but consistent shift of ~`0.000000007`. Is this normal?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


std::vector< double > readFromFile(const std::string& file_name) {
    std::vector< double > values;
    std::ifstream file(file_name.data(), std::ios::in);
    file.precision(9);   // makes no difference
    double value = 0.0;
    if (file.is_open()){
        while (file >> value) {
            values.push_back(value);
        }    
        file.close();
    }
    return values;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    auto vals = readFromFile("src/samples.txt");

    std::cout.precision(9);
    for (auto& val : vals) {
        std::cout <<  std::fixed << val << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My `samples.txt`:

```
1595519203.966806166
1595519204.000087015
1595519204.033377640
1595519204.066651098
```

And the code output:

```
1595519203.966806173
1595519204.000087023 
1595519204.033377647
1595519204.066651106
```

This is something I have never dealt with, and am left wondering if the issue is in how the file is read, or in how I am printing it.

Comment: You could always view the data in memory with a debugger. Hint, the numbers you have printed are within the tolerance of `double` is at least 15 digits of decimal precision (according to IEEE 754). Try using `long double` if `double` is insuffcient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the range of 10^10, 64-bit [IEEE 754 double-precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) have a precision of about 10^-6. So, yes, this inconsistency is normal and cannot be avoided.

If you want higher precision, then you might want to try using `long double`. Some platforms provide hardware or software support for 80-bit or 128-bit floating point numbers. However, on some platforms (such as the Microsoft C++ compiler), `long double` is equivalent to 64-bit `double`.

If also `long double` is not sufficient, then you will have to revert to using a software [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library. This will probably be slower, but allows for arbitrary precision.

Comment: `long double` might have more precision than `double`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Thanks, I have edited my answer to address your comment.